# Moviepy - OSError: Error in file converted_fg01.mp4, Accessing time t=1352.40-1352.45 seconds, with clip duration=1352.400000 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy, oserror

I'm using moviepy to cut a clip into multiple equally-sized segments, and it's reading from a txt file of start and end values to cut the clip properly. The following is my code:

```py
required_video_file = VideoFileClip(filename)
with open("times.txt") as f:
  times = f.readlines()
times = [x.strip() for x in times] 
fullduration = required_video_file.duration
for time in times:
  starttime = int(time.split("-")[0])
  endtime = int(time.split("-")[1])
  subclip = required_video_file.subclip(starttime, endtime)
  filen = str(times.index(time)+1)+".mp4"
  if starttime >= fullduration:
    print(f"Video too short to complete request! Quitting loop..")
    break
  if endtime >= fullduration:
    print(f"Cropping endtime from {endtime} to {fullduration}!")
    endtime = None
  subclip.write_videofile(filen, audio_codec='aac')
```

The current filename value is a 20-ish minute clip which has the `times.txt` file cut up into 30-second portions:

```
0-30
30-60
60-90
90-120
120-150
```

And so on. However, I get an OSerror when it tries to write the final value in the sequence:

`OSError: Error in file converted_fg01.mp4, Accessing time t=1352.40-1352.45 seconds, with clip duration=1352.400000 seconds,`

The code is registering and activating the `if` loop for if the endtime is greater than the full duration, but it's still outputting the error, no matter if i set it to the duration, to None, or any other possible fix I've tried.

> 

FULL ERROR:

```
Cropping endtime of 1380 to 1352.4!
Moviepy - Building video 46.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in 46TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4
chunk:   0%|                                                                          | 0/662 [00:00<?, ?it/s, now=None]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vidsplitter.py", line 80, in <module>
    subclip.write_videofile(filen, audio_codec='aac')
  File "<decorator-gen-60>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 56, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-59>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 135, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-58>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 24, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-57>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 332, in write_videofile
    self.audio.write_audiofile(
  File "<decorator-gen-46>", line 2, in write_audiofile
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 56, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-45>", line 2, in write_audiofile
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 230, in write_audiofile
    return ffmpeg_audiowrite(
  File "<decorator-gen-9>", line 2, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 56, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 204, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
    for chunk in clip.iter_chunks(
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 90, in iter_chunks
    yield self.to_soundarray(
  File "<decorator-gen-43>", line 2, in to_soundarray
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 56, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 138, in to_soundarray
    snd_array = self.get_frame(tt)
  File "<decorator-gen-11>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 98, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 141, in <lambda>
    newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 193, in <lambda>
    lambda gf, t: gf(t_func(t)), apply_to, keep_duration=keep_duration
  File "<decorator-gen-11>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 98, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/AudioFileClip.py", line 88, in <lambda>
    self.make_frame = lambda t: self.reader.get_frame(t)
  File "/Users/hypnoticocelot/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/readers.py", line 183, in get_frame
    raise IOError(
OSError: Error in file converted_fg01.mp4, Accessing time t=1352.40-1352.45 seconds, with clip duration=1352.400000 seconds,
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to make the checks in your `if` statements before calling `required_video_file.subclip()` rather than after?  For example, if `endtime` is larger than the duration of the file, you set `endtime = None`, but this has no real effect, because you already called `.subclip(starttime, endtime)` with the original value of `endtime`.

Comment: Now that i see that, that's the issue lol. Mind creating an answer so I can upvote you and mark you as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Move the call to `.subclip()` so it's after the `if` statements, and hence the corrected `endtime` is used:

```
for time in times:
  starttime = int(time.split("-")[0])
  endtime = int(time.split("-")[1])
  filen = str(times.index(time)+1)+".mp4"
  if starttime >= fullduration:
    print(f"Video too short to complete request! Quitting loop..")
    break
  if endtime >= fullduration:
    print(f"Cropping endtime from {endtime} to {fullduration}!")
    endtime = None
  subclip = required_video_file.subclip(starttime, endtime) # Moved this line so that it uses the corrected endtime
  subclip.write_videofile(filen, audio_codec='aac')
```